# qemu перезапускается в 32 битном режиме

Tags: ассемблер, ос, assembly, qemu, protected

я плохо разбираюсь в терминах, но небольшое представление есть.

Я сделал загрузочный сектор (он запускается), который загружает программу, переводящий в 32 битный режим

все работает, но каждую секунду (или вроде того) просто идет перезапуск

*** нужно поставить jmp $ в конце программы

boot.asm

```
org 0x7c00

mov [bootDisk], dl

call successBootSectorMessage
call diskRead

%include "/Users/MatviCoolk/Beast/bootSector/printString.asm"
%include "/Users/MatviCoolk/Beast/bootSector/diskRead.asm"
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

printString.asm

```
printString:

 mov ah, 0Eh
    .printCharacter:
        lodsb

    cmp al, 0x00
    je .done

    int 10h

    jmp .printCharacter

.done:
    ret

successBootSectorMessage:
mov si, .message
call printString

ret

.message:
    db "OK: Boot sector", 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x00

driveReadFailMessage:
mov si, .message
call printString

ret

.message:
    db "FAIL: Reading boot drive", 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x0a, "Maybe system or a boot sector containts an error", 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x00
```

diskRead.asm:

```
    postBootSector equ 0x7e00

diskRead:
   

 mov ah, 0x02
    mov bx, postBootSector
    mov dl, [bootDisk]
    mov al, 4
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02

    int 0x13
    jc driveReadFailMessage

    jmp postBootSector

    ret

bootDisk:
    db 0
```

start.asm:

```
org 0x7e00
%include "/Users/MatviCoolk/Beast/postBootSector/enteringProtectedMode.asm"
times 2048-($-$$) db 0
```

enteringProtectedMode.asm

```
jmp enterProtectedMode

%include "/Users/MatviCoolk/Beast/postBootSector/protectedMode/gdt.asm"

enterProtectedMode:
    call enableA20
    cli
    lgdt [gdtDescriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 3
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp codeSeg:startProtectedMode

enableA20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    ret

[bits 32]

startProtectedMode:
    mov [0xb85a0], byte '3'
    mov [0xb85a2], byte '2'
    mov [0xb85a6], byte 'b'
    mov [0xb85a8], byte 'i'
    mov [0xb85aa], byte 't'
```

gdt.asm

```
gdtNullDesc:
    dd 0
    dd 0

gdtCodeDesc:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x00

gdtDataDesc:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x00

gdtEnd:

gdtDescriptor:
    gdtSize:
        dw gdtEnd - gdtNullDesc - 1
        dd gdtNullDesc

codeSeg equ gdtCodeDesc - gdtNullDesc
dataSeg equ gdtDataDesc - gdtNullDesc
```

Comment: "Я сделал загрузочный сектор" - какой? MaserBoot или Boot

Comment: @Виктор, честно, я очень плохо разбираюсь. я прикрепил все файлы моего проекта. возможно это master boot, который 512 байт. заранее спасибо, если поможете.

Comment: Вам будет сложно это сделать. Надо знать архитектуру ЦПУ. например Вы не установили дескриптор таблицы прерываний и т.п.

Comment: Если вы разобрались с вашей проблемой, добавьте решение ответом. Добавлять Solved/Решено в заголовок не нужно.

Comment: @insolor Сделал.

Comment: @MatviCoolk, ответ добавьте в поле "Ваш ответ" ниже. Тогда будет видно, что у вопроса есть какое-то решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце программы нужно поставить jmp $

Точно не знаю почему.